# Import error for openpyxl

Tags: python, arcgis, openpyxl

I'm very very new to coding and I'm having an issue importing openpyxl into my python program. I imagine the issue is due to where I have it saved on my computer.

I've downloaded other libraries (xlrd, xlwt, xlutils) before and just saved them in my: C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib, or C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\site-packages, or C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.1\Lib, or C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.1\Lib\site-packages directories and python has been able to "see" them when i import them into a script.

I've done some trolling on the web and it looks like I may be performing the "installation" of openpyxl incorrectly. I downloaded "setuptools-5.7" in order to try to run the setup.py script contained within the openpyxl library, and so far I haven't gotten that to work out.

Since I'm so new to python, I don't really understand some of the other stuff I've been finding about how to correctly install the library, like "pip install" etc.

If anyone has any ideas about how I can install or save or locate the openpyxl library in the easiest fashion (without using other programs that I don't already have), that would be great!

Comment: What *exactly* is the problem? Can you post the error message, and the stack trace if appropriate?

Comment: here is what I am trying to do:

from openpyxl import Workbook

Comment: ...and this is the error it throws:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\Tools\Quicklook Tool\openpyxl.py", line 2, in <module>
    from openpyxl import Workbook
  File "D:\Users\Tools\Quicklook Tool\openpyxl.py", line 2, in <module>
    from openpyxl import Workbook
ImportError: cannot import name Workbook

Answer (score 0):

Your import is probably incorrect.

It needs to be.

```
from openpyxl import workbook
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought that too, but it throws the same error. 

ImportError: cannot import name workbook

I believe the problem centers around how and where the library is installed.

Comment: How did you install the library?  using pip, easy_install or something else?

Comment: As of now, all I have done is put the unzipped folder in my library directories (shown above). I don't know what pip, or easy install is. I'm currently running python 2.7, if that helps

Comment: Okay so pip and easy_install are simple ways of installing python libraries, but you have to have them installed I'm assuming you don't at the moment.   To install a library without them just go to the directory where you unzipped your openpyxl.  In the directory from the command line type >>python setup.py install<< (don't type the >><< of course)

this should print out installing notes etc...

Comment: That went off without a hitch it seems, but still when i call  "from openpyxl import workbook" it still errors out and says it cannot import workbook.

Comment: Sorry i'm not really sure. the last thing I would suggest is the capitalize Workbook --> from openpyxl import Workbook

Comment: Hmm. I may retry downloading openpyxl and see if I can get it to work

Comment: As Chris says you should capitalise `Workbook`. But also please learn how to install Python code. Simply copying files to a directory will often not work.